# Php clear up array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

i have this array printed out with print_r.

```
Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => 25742 ) Array ( [0] => 72727 ) Array ( [0] => 2752 ) Array ( [0] => 72752 ) Array ( [0] => 72572 ) Array ( [0] => 25325 ) Array ( [0] => 7272 ) Array ( [0] => 27272 ) Array ( [0] => 727542 ) Array ( ) Array ( )
```

But i want this output:

```
Array ( [0] => 25742 )
Array ( [0] => 72727 )
Array ( [0] => 2752 )
Array ( [0] => 72752 )
Array ( [0] => 72572 )
Array ( [0] => 25325 )
Array ( [0] => 7272 ) 
Array ( [0] => 27272 )
Array ( [0] => 727542 )
```

So only the Arrays with the Number in, and reindexed.

Comment: please show us your source with the `print_r`

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I assume that this code is inside a loop. So Simply check if the array is empty or not before you print it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter to get it. **[Live demo](https://eval.in/788525)**

```
$array = array(array(), array(), array(9), array(8));
$arr = array_filter($array);
print_r($arr);
```